# Upgrading PHP pear and pecl

Tags: php, pear, pecl

I am using Amazon Linux AMI. I have PHP5.4 installed.

```
php -v
```

gives

```
PHP 5.4.13 (cli) (built: Mar 29 2013 20:29:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

when I do `pear -V`

```
PEAR Version: 1.10.1
PHP Version: 5.3.29
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Linux ip-10-0-1-160 4.1.7-15.23.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 14 23:20:33 UTC 2015 x86_64
```

and `pecl -V` gives

```
PEAR Version: 1.10.1
PHP Version: 5.3.29
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Linux ip-10-0-1-160 4.1.7-15.23.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 14 23:20:33 UTC 2015 x86_64
```

My question is the PHP versions shown in `pear` and `pecl` command are different from `php -v`

When I install another module using `pecl <module>`, it gives

```
Warning: PHP Startup: <module>: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
```

## EDIT

I found out that there are two php installations

`/usr/bin/php -v` gives

```
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: May 12 2015 22:42:19) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

and

`/usr/local/bin/php -v` gives

```
PHP 5.4.13 (cli) (built: Mar 29 2013 20:29:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I want to use the PHP 5.4 version and install modules using pear and pecl. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you install pecl with Yum? Most all pecl packages are distributed in Yum... with AWS Linux, you can even use the IUS Repos to get more PHP extensions. http://iuscommunity.org I would clear out all the pecl extensions installed via the pecl CLI and use Yum... they will line up with your version of PHP if PHP was installed VIA Yum

Comment: I used yum. As I mentioned in the edit, there are two versions of php. How can I configure and install pear and pecl with with PHP 5.4 and then try to install the module.

Comment: I would remove one of the php installations... and what's the module you are trying to install?

Comment: I am trying to install http://gearman.org/

Comment: This is not a programming question and as such off-topic here. That said, set up a new machine with a halfway-recent PHP installation, not one that hasn't received **security updates** for ages. Then, migrate your infrastructure to the new machine and finally recycle the old one, if the new one works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing pear using yum

```
sudo yum -y remove php-pear
```

I then installed pear this way

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
/usr/local/bin/php -q php-phar
```

Now  `pear -V` shows

```
PEAR Version: 1.10.1
PHP Version: 5.4.13
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by telling PEAR to use the 5.4 version of PHP... Maybe try this:

First, make note of all the current settings in case you need to roll back:

```
pear config-show
```

Once you have that info copied and saved somewhere, make the change:

```
pear config-set php_bin /usr/local/bin/php
```

Comment: thanks. I did what you said, but 
pear -V still shows PHP Version: 5.3.29

Answer (score 0):

In  your .bashrc (or equivalent if you're not using bash), you need to set an environment variable, named PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN to the location of the php binary that you want to use:

```
export PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=/usr/local/bin/php
```